# Owl carousel having wrong Next and Previous label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I'm using this template from colorlib(https://colorlib.com/wp/template/aranoz/). The problem is the Next and Previous labels on the buttons of slider are wrongly. Next is labelled as previous and Previous is labelled as Next. You can clearly see this on the slider when you preview the template. I'm attaching a snip as well.
Can anyone help me how to correct this?

Thank you in advance[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it resolved.
It was in custom.js file. I had to swap the places of previous and next.
Previously they were as

```
navText: ["next", "previous"],
```

After changing to below, it is showing properly.

```
navText: ["previous", "next"],
```